# Error in Passing values to URL for Advance searching in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a search function for searching products in `woocommerce`.
SO URL will be like "http://localhost/wp/?s=123&post_type=product".

User will search anything website will be searched and additionally product's custom field will be searched. This code work fine with http://localhost/wp/?s=123 but when `"http://localhost/wp/?s=123&post_type=product` is entered in url then it say No product is found.

**Code is given below**

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
global $pagenow, $wpdb;


    if ( is_search() ) {
$where = preg_replace("/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product') ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

So What modification is required?

`URL` http://localhost/wp/?orderby=date&post_type=product work fine

Answer (score 0):

You write $wpdb->posts in "",thats why its not working. 
You check it below.

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
global $pagenow, $wpdb;


    if ( is_search() ) {
$where = preg_replace("/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where .= " AND (".$wpdb->posts.".post_type = 'product') ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

Comment: I'm positive that is not the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: another hint is that it works on `?s=123`  and not on `?s=123&post_type=product`